# Derivative estimate of polynomial given norm on curve

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $Q$ denote an $n$th degree polynomial and $\Gamma$ some Jordan curve. If we know that $\|Q\|_{\Gamma}\leq M$ I then want to show that
$$|Q'(z)|\leq M\mathrm{dist}(z,\Gamma)^{-1}$$
for any $z$ on the interior of $\Gamma$.

I don't know how to do this, my guess was to use the Cauchy integral formula but it doesn't give good enough estimates:

$$Q'(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\Gamma}\frac{Q(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^2}\mathrm{d}\zeta\Rightarrow |Q'(z)|\leq \frac{M\cdot L(\Gamma)}{2\pi\mathrm{dist}(z,\Gamma)^2}$$

How could one show the better inequality above?

Answer (score 1):

I found a partial solution:

Let $f(w) = \frac{Q(z)-Q(w)}{z-w}$ then $f$ is holomorphic with $f(z) = Q'(z)$ and on this function we can apply the maximum principle which gives us that
$$|Q'(z)|\leq \frac{\max_{w\in \Gamma}|Q(z)-Q(w)|}{\mathrm{dist}(z,\Gamma)}\leq \frac{2M}{\mathrm{dist}(z,\Gamma)}$$